# CSS translation bug in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, z-index, transition

I'm facing a weird bug with Firefox.
I have a side menu, with a static position.

When I am in smartphone format, this menu disappears after a menu item is selected. The menu slides to the left and disappears. Then I have a back button to make the inverse action.

It works great with Chrome, but in Firefox, when I click on the back button, the menu slides to the right, and some elements of the page stay visible above the menu until the CSS translateX has finished. Then, these elements are correctly hidden behind the menu.

The z-index property is correctly set. The bug comes only during the translation.

See the screenshot below (back button, icons and price shouldn't be above the menu) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2X8M.png

Page structure looks like this :

```
<div>
    <aside id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Menu 1</li>
            <li>Menu 2</li>
            <li>Menu 3</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <div id="page">
    Lorem ispum dolor sit amet
    </div>
</div>
```

Style of the side menu (React JSS) :

```
aside: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  zIndex: 10,
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  width: '100%',
  transition: 'transform .7s',
  '&.hidden': { transform: 'translateX(-105%)' }
}
```

Any idea ?

**Update :** I tried to change the translateX with a left property.
I kept the transition, but put it on the left property.
It's working great.
But I don't understand why translate is causing this bug in Firefox

Comment: Hello there ! Please post your code so that we could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Use This -

```
aside: {
 position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  zIndex: 10,
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  width: '100%',
  '-webkit-transition': '-webkit-transform 0.7s',
  '-moz-transition': '-moz-transform 0.7s',
   transition: 'transform 0.7s',
  '&.hidden': { '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(-105%)',
                '-moz-transform': 'translateX(-105%)',
                transform: 'translateX(-105%)' }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but no change. Transform and transition properties don't need vendor anymore for Firefox. I checked on caniuse.com